# How to check if a best offer was accepted on a sold listing on ebay? (Python + Beautifulsoup)

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a simple Flask API in python that grabs all the sold listings for a particular item on Ebay. All I want it to do it take in a search input string, and it will return all the sold listings. So for example, if I search "oakley sunglasses" it will return all the recently sold sunglasses with the title, price, date sold, and whether a best offer was accepted or not. I was able grab all the information using beautifulsoup, but unfortunately I've been stuck trying to figure out the best offer part.

If a best offer was accepted, the price would have a strikethrough in it. My initial thoughts were to check if a span exists with the classname STRIKETHROUGH POSITIVE, then it would indicate a best offer was accepted. If a best offer was accepted, it would say Y/N in the JSON being returned. I am not aware of any other ways of checking if a best offer was accepted other than checking for this strikethrough.

[image]

To see this, you would have to search an item (i.e. oakley sunglasses) on ebay, then on the left hand side, scroll all the way down and filter by "Sold items")

I have tried the following:

- Double checking the user-agents to match my current browser
- Extracting the element and seeing if any styling was applied to it
- Adding print/logging statements, it doesn't seem to show the STRIKETHROUGH portion in the elements at all, but when I inspect in Chrome/Firefox it shows up just fine.
- Tried extracting the parent container, then inspecting the child container, still doesn't show the strikethrough.
- Tried using selenium with a wait built in, to see if it would dynamically render and I still face the same issue.

The code:

```
def query_ebay_listings(query):
    url = f"https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw={query.replace(' ', '+')}&_ipg=100&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        app.logger.info('Executed query..')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        
        #if nothing shows up on ebay's side
        if "No results found" in response.text:
            app.logger.info('No results were found in the query, exiting')
            return {"data" : "No results found!"}

        sold_items = soup.find_all('div', class_='s-item__wrapper clearfix')

        app.logger.info(len(sold_items))

        if not sold_items:
            app.logger.info("No sold items found on the page.")

            return {"data" : "No results found!"}
        
        data = []
        for item in sold_items:

            #error handling where if one of the elements were missing it would fail

            titleElement = item.find('div', class_='s-item__title')
            title = titleElement.text.strip() if titleElement else '<Title not found>'

            if "Shop on eBay" in title: #ignore first element, idk why it's there
                continue

            priceElement = item.find('span', class_='s-item__price') 
            
            bestOffer = 'N'    
           


            item_info = item.find('div', class_='s-item__info')

         
            ### this doesn't work 
            price_container = item_info.find('span', class_='STRIKETHROUGH POSITIVE')

            print(price_container) #prints "None"
         
            if price_container:
                bestOffer = 'Y'
                

            price = priceElement.text.strip() if priceElement else '<Price not found>'

            date_element = item.find('span', class_='POSITIVE')
            date = date_element.text.strip() if date_element else '<Date not found>'

            href_element = item.find('a', class_='s-item__link')
            href = href_element['href'] if href_element and 'href' in href_element.attrs else '<href not found>'

            

            data.append({
                "title" : title,
                "price" : price,
                "date" : date,
                "url": href,
                "bestOffer" : bestOffer
            })

        return{"data" : data}

    else:
        app.logger.info('Query failed to execute')


    return response.status_code
```

An example output I want:

```
    {
      "bestOffer": "N",
      "date": "Sold  Jan 18, 2024",
      "price": "$400.00",
      "title": "Oakley sunglasses 1",
      "url": <url goes here>
    },
    {
      "bestOffer": "Y",
      "date": "Sold  Jan 18, 2024",
      "price": "$175.00",
      "title": "Oakley glasses 2",
      "url": <url goes here>
    }
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the styling you're seeing - when I search for that product, I get a row that has the "POSITIVE" class, but not "STRIKETHROUGH". Perhaps it's browser-dependent?

Comment: @ajc2000 I was thinking it might've been my browser too, but I'm not sure if it is. I tried changing the class from STRIKETHROUGH POSITIVE to s-item__price and printing it out, but it doesn't show any STRIKETHROUGHS whatsoever.

Comment: Try using playwright instead of selenium, much newer python library and doesn't require webdrivers, installation and docs [here](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro).